# Loop images until the audio ends

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio

I have an audio file 2 hours long and 30 still images related to the audio. I would like to display each image consecutively for about 45 seconds while the audio is playing in a repeating fashion. When the last image has been displayed, I want to just start over from the top and keep repeating the images in a circle until the audio ends.

For testing the technique purposes I am using this command with shorter audio, only 2 images, and shorter durations. The music plays, the images display and transition as desired but how do I get them to repeat? It just displays the two images and stops. How do I get the images to loop continuously until the audio ends?

I'm using ffmpeg on Linux Mint 20.

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers

ffmpeg -i "/home/ron/fftest/Overture.mp3" \
           -loop 1 -i "/home/ron/fftest/Picture1.jpg" \
           -loop 1 -i "/home/ron/fftest/Picture2.jpg" \
           -filter_complex \
             "[1:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v1]; \
              [2:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v2]; \
              [v1][v2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" \
           -shortest -movflags +faststart -map 0:a -map [v] -c:a copy \
           /home/ron/fftest/Overture.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have an audio file, which is named as "audio.mp3";
you have images file pattern as "Picture01.jpg", "Picture02.jpg", ... "Picture30.jpg"; and you want 4.5s image duration. Then the command is

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 1/4.5 -i Picture%2d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg result.mp4
```

Good luck!